# I want to store values in variables then display in table but this wouldn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store result first in variables so I could use them but this wouldn't iterate anything. See I tried to store row's values in variables first and called them in td of table but it shows nothing.

Does it have a syntax error or something. What could be the method to store in variables first?

```
 $query_test = "SELECT itemname, categoryname, manufacturername,
                       price, shopname,itemurl, itemimage, typename  
                FROM prices p, 
                     items i, 
                     shops s, 
                     categories c, 
                     manufacturers m, 
                     types t, 
                    modules mo 
                WHERE p.shopid=s.shopid 
                  AND i.categoryid=c.categoryid 
                  AND p.itemid=i.itemid 
                  AND i.ManufacturerId=m.ManufacturerID 
                  AND i.ModuleId= mo.ModuleID 
                  AND i.TypeId=t.TypeID 
                  AND i.categoryid=1004 
                  AND s.shopid=5003";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_test);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr><td>"."Name"."</td>";
 echo "<td>"."Category"."</td>";
 echo "<td>"."Manufacturer"."</td>";
 echo "<td>"."Price"."</td>";
 echo "<td>"."Shop"."</td>";
 echo "<td>"."Type"."</td>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    //output a row here
    $name = $row['itemname'];
    $category = $row['categoryname'];
    $manufacturer = $row['manufacturername'];
    $price = $row['price']:
    $shop = $row['shopname'];
    $type = $row['typename'];
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$category."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$manufacturer."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$price."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$shop."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$type."</td></tr>";
    /*echo "<tr><td>".($row['itemname'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($row['categoryname'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($row['manufacturername'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($row['price'])."</td>";
     echo "<td>".($row['shopname'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".($row['typename'])."</td></tr>";*/
 }

 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If that does not work, then it is likely that your query did not work and there are no rows to output

Comment: did you check if your query actually returned anything? Or if the code executed at all? **WHAT** shows nothing? The entire html doesn't show? Or just where you expect your query results to be?

Comment: Show more of your code please! From where you query for this data

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP Error log recently?

Comment: Can you see any errors?

Comment: My query works fine. The commented code works just fine Any ways I have updated my query code

Comment: OMGGGGGGGG look at this $price = $row['price']:  and I have been banging my head over whats wrong with it!!!!

Comment: Where have you been for the last 15 years, have you heard of JOIN

Comment: And `$var` is automatically expanded in a double quoted string so all that concatenation is totally unnecessay and probably what confused you

Comment: I do use JOINS but honestly they really confuse me! I should get a teacher who would teach me JOINS properly. Can you post this sql query in JOINs I will tickmark your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Do a `var_dump($row)` in your while loop to see what values are stored in `$row`.

Also, given how you are accessing them, you should probably do:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```